# Angular Change Detection not triggering on Router.navigate()

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a component in Angular called `NewEventComponent` that only contains a form to submit a new event. On it's submit method it has this code:

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.isSendingRequest = true;

  this.geolocationService.geocodeAddress(this.location.value).subscribe(
    (results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[]) => {
      if (results && results.length) {
        const eventData: EventData = {
          name: this.name.value,
          location: [results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()],
          startDate: this.datetimeService.convertDateAndTimeToISOString(this.startDate.value, this.startTime.value),
          endingDate: this.datetimeService.convertDateAndTimeToISOString(this.endingDate.value, this.endingTime.value),
          description: this.description.value,
          sport: this.sport.value,
          intensity: this.intensity.value,
          fee: this.fee.value,
          maxPlayers: this.maxPlayers.value
        };

        this.eventService.createEvent(eventData).subscribe(
          (res: any) => {
            this.alertService.createAlert({ message: EVENT_CREATED_MESSAGE, type: AlertType.Success });
            this.router.navigate(['events', res.data.event.id]);
          }
        );
      } else {
        this.handleInvalidLocationError();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

It only sends the event to the server and redirects to the event page, which is the `EventDetails` component. This component only asks for the requested event to the server and passes it as an Input to a child component. This is the code:

TS:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-details',
  templateUrl: './event-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-details.component.scss']
})
export class EventDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  private event: EventResponse;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private eventService: EventService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvent();
  }

  getEvent(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.eventService.getEvent(params.id).subscribe(
          (res: any) => {
            this.event = res.data.event;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="info-wrapper">
      <app-event-details-info [event]="event">
      </app-event-details-info>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the child component `EventDetailsInfo` only receives the event as an Input like this `@Input() event: EventResponse;` and displays the information in the html like this: `<h5>{{ event?.name }}</h5>`.

The problem here is that when navigating from the `NewEvent` component to the `EventDetails` component, the change detection is not triggered, so until I click anywhere in the DOM for example, the changes are not showing. But when I navigate to the `EventDetails` component trough the url directly the page is rendering properly.

What am I missing on change detection? Any idea? Thanks!

PS: `EventService` only executes HTTP calls and return them as Observables, like:

```js
createEvent(eventData: EventData): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/events/`, eventData);
}

getEvent(eventId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/events/${eventId}`);
}
```

PS2: This is the `GeolocationService` method used in the ´onSubmit()´ method:

```
geocodeAddress(address: string): Observable<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]> {
  const response: Subject<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]>
    = new Subject<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]>();
  const request: google.maps.GeocoderRequest = { address };

  this.geocoder.geocode(request,
    (results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[]) => {
      response.next(results);
    }
  );

  return response;
}
```

Comment: What is `EventService`? Perhaps the event is emitted outside Angulars zone.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the service method, it only has http calls

Comment: Perhaps a problem with the route configuration. Please try to create a minimal reproduction in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: Ok, It's a complex app but I'll try to create a simple reproduction later and post it here. I'm very lost with this issue...

Comment: Only add what is absolutely necessary to reproduce. Everything else is just noise that makes it difficult to track down the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will try. One missing point I didn't say before is that I'm using the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in the `NewEventComponent` to set errors to a reactive form programmatically. Can this be related to the change detection not working properly?

Comment: No, `detectChanges()` can in the worst case only hurt performance, but `detectChanges`only runs change detection for the the component. `router.navigate()` involves other (non-descendant) components which `detectChanges()`won't cover and requires `zone.run()` (depending on what actually causes the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
onSubmit() {
  this.isSendingRequest = true;

  this.geolocationService.geocodeAddress(this.location.value).subscribe(
    (results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[]) => {
      this.zone.run(() => π
        if (results && results.length) {
            const eventData: EventData = {
              name: this.name.value,
              location: [results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()],
              startDate: this.datetimeService.convertDateAndTimeToISOString(this.startDate.value, this.startTime.value),
              endingDate: this.datetimeService.convertDateAndTimeToISOString(this.endingDate.value, this.endingTime.value),
              description: this.description.value,
              sport: this.sport.value,
              intensity: this.intensity.value,
              fee: this.fee.value,
              maxPlayers: this.maxPlayers.value
            };

            this.eventService.createEvent(eventData).subscribe(
              (res: any) => {
                this.alertService.createAlert({ message: EVENT_CREATED_MESSAGE, type: AlertType.Success });
                this.router.navigate(['events', res.data.event.id]);
              }
            );
          } else {
            this.handleInvalidLocationError();
          }
        }
     });
  );
}
```

**Original**

Perhaps the event is emitted outside Angular zone.

Try:

```js
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
```

and:

```js
this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['events', res.data.event.id]));
```

If this solves the issue, you should fix `EventService`

Comment: I've tried this and it solves the problem, but I don't understand why... It is a service problem then?

Comment: It's probably the service, but hard to tell. The code you shared looks fine.

Comment: I think I've encountered the problem... But I don't understand it very good. I want to post a minimal code so it was clear to understand but I was missing that I'm using a `GeolocationService` when submitting the form... I've updated my answer with the full code of the `GeolocationService` and the `onSubmit()` method. So now, I think the problem is with the `GeolocationService` right? If you could update your answer will make my day!

Comment: It's very likely that this causes the problem. I'd run the code in the callback within `zone.run(...)` to force execution back into Angulars zone, then you don't need to care anywhere else. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Finally what I did is invoking the `zone.run(...)` method inside of the `GeolocationService` method. So, when the service emits the next value of the Subject it's inside the Angular Zone, so after any subscription to that method the change detection is triggered.

Comment: Sounds great :)

Comment: Yep! The problem was that the `Google JS library` uses `JSONP` to fetch the Google APIS, so it's running outside the Angular Zone.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the order of when the subscription occurs, you could be missing the event entirely.  Consider using `shareReplay(1)` and exposing an event.

Alternatively, move the subscription of the event to the constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private eventService: EventService
  ) { 
     this.getEvent();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```